# How to set Minimum, maximum and interval value for time in Chart Control (point chart)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have fetch data of last 24 hours through stored procedure and I want to plot these data into Point chart. Result of the SP is

[image]

on X-Axis : LocationName.....
on Y-axis : TrackTimeStamp

I have written following code for plotting point

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=10.182.37.210;Initial Catalog=ECSGCore_QA2;User Id=sa;pwd=sa@1234;");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Sp_GetAssetLocation",con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AssetId", 32);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            chart1.DataSource = dt;
            chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Title = "Location";
            chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Title = "Time";
            //chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Minimum = 
            //chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Maximum = 
            //chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Interval = 
            chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "LocationName";
            chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "TrackTimeStamp";
            con.Close();
```

**And My result is :**

[image]

**My Questions :**

1. how to set minimum value like 0:00/12:00 AM and maximum value like 24:00/12:00 PM??
2. I want to set interval of 2 hours starting from
   12:00 AM to 12:00 PM. How it is possible?
3. When I zoom in my chart
   interval should be change from 2 hour to 1 hour. Is it possible? How
   to complete my task?
4. Location name should be distinct. "Eitra_FirstFloor_2" display 4 times.
5. How to make link (hyperlink) of the point. on click event some another information shows.

Comment: You have tagged your question with win forms (which is mentioned in the question) and with three "asp.net"-related tags, which are not mentioned in the question. Some clarification is needed

Comment: This question is for windows application not for web and we can set minimum value, maximum value and interval for our chart but this is only possible for decimal values. I don't know how to use use this property for time? I have mention my requirement in my questions.

Comment: I've removed the asp.net-related tags from the question now

Answer (score 1):

In Charts time is represented as double, and the min (0:00) = 0.0, the max (24:00) = 1.0.
Setting min and max:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0.7;
```

In this case the minX is set to cca 17:00 (17 / 24 = 0.7)

I believe that the interval is set in the same way